# Why is my system running Android Studio slow?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am starting Flutter programming
My laptop hangs when running Android Studio2022. Laptop specifications
ram:8g ddr3 1600
cpu: cor i5 3337U 1.8 Ghz
SSD:120G
vga:2G 740M
Do you suggest installing the old version of Android Studio or upgrading the laptop?

Android Studio is installed and running, but it does not run to test the Android device and the device hangs, could it be due to the hardware?

Comment: I suggest you upgrade your laptop, because ram should be at least 12 gb, 8gb ram is manageable. Also, your cpu is not powerful so build time will be very high. You have ssd, that's good but cpu should be more powerful. Also, you should not ask questions like this on StackOverflow. You should only ask programming questions here. These questions are suitable for other forums.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. Yes, unfortunately, I am a newbie. I didn't know that I shouldn't ask such questions. Thank of you for help